# wx.Image is throwing PyAssertionError

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I ran the following python code

```
import wx

class myframe(wx.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title="Hello")
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        qmi = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, 100, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q')
        qmi.SetBitmap(wx.Image(
            'quit.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap())
        fileMenu.AppendItem(qmi)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=100)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.SetSize((250, 200))
        self.SetTitle('Icons and shortcuts')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    myframe()
    ex.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above code is throwing the message

```
qmi.SetBitmap(wx.Image('quit.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 2882, in __init__
    _core_.Image_swiginit(self,_core_.new_Image(*args, **kwargs))
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1449) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
```

I am new to python and completely unable to solve this.
Is there anyway to find the solution to this.

I am using python 2.7.10 and wxpython 3.0.2.0 in a windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that only occurred following a cxFreeze with wxPhoenix. I worried that the solution above could cause issues on a machine that wasn't wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, so instead, I recorded the locale before any imports (which I suspected were changing the locale):

```
import wx
locale = wx.Locale.GetSystemLanguage()
```

And then reset it after my imports and after creating the app:

```
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
app.locale = wx.Locale(locale)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to modify the locale and it is working. 
Modified the code as here:

```
def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    ex.locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
    myframe()
    ex.MainLoop()
```

Locale is conflicting with system locale. So modified it in the code for this program.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed if you included some wx.App code:

```py
    def InitLocale(self):
        import sys

        if sys.platform.startswith("win") and sys.version_info > (3, 8):
            import locale

            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")
```

Also, it was fixed correctly in wx4.2 which was just released. If you hit this bug, it was never you. wx and python were disagreeing about the locale. It hits intermittently and only for some non-English locale. 4.2 fixes, or the above code snipple to get rid of the local for post py3.8.